# How to Find Previous Declared Settings?

Tags: xml, configuration

In a service project for Azure, when I compile my code I am receiving numerous warnings similar to this: "The complexType 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration:AddressAssignmentsElement' has already been declared."

I have basic, cloud and local service configuration files.

How do I find the referenced setting?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the referenced setting, but I did discover the "XML > Schemas" tool, which is available when the primary configuration files are loaded, that allowed me to exclude the duplicating schemas and eliminate the warnings.

[image]